# What do these symbols indicate on the ATC display?

Tags: air-traffic-control, display

I just got found ATC controller display on the internet and could you tell me what are these symbols indicating? For example the ones I highlighted in red?

[image]

Comment: You might want to refer to the manual: https://www.ivao.aero/softdev/ivac.asp#doc

Answer (score 5):

The white squares are aircraft - it's course is indicated by a line. Then there is a datablock showing Callsign "FWA170C", its altitude F053 = Flighlevel 53 = 5300ft, climbing to an assigned flightlevel 190 = 19000ft.
A = altitude - below a defined transition level
F = flightlevel (steps of 100ft) - above a defined transition altitude

Transition altitude and level depend on the location and weather.

Then you have the airports, navaids, nav-fixes and the control zones showing.

Comment: I believe the C in FWA170 C (there is a space, I believe) might be transponder mode being Mode-C.

Comment: @tsg thanks and how could the ATC know the aircraft is climbing to FL190? Is that reported by the aircraft?

Comment: @SentryRaven C is an indication of the current sector ("Center").

Comment: @VvV Please get in touch with the IVAO training department. They have plenty of helpful resources.

Comment: @J. Hougaard some Aircraft has a ident end with "T", what does that mean?

Comment: @VvV http://forum.ivao.aero/

Comment: To add to the answer... The long white line between the FWA170C (data block) and the small white square (airplane) is just there to connect the data legend to an airplane... following the line from the airplane let's you find the data associated with that aircraft.

Comment: ATC knows they're climbing to FL190 because that's what ATC told them to do...

Comment: @Jan, yes, and the short line coming out of the centre of the square is the current movement vector. I think its length is 5 min of flight, but I don't remember exactly now.